# How do I use Nagios to monitor a log file that generates a random ID

Tags: linux, bash, logging, monitoring, nagios

This the log file that I want to monitor:

```
/test/James-2018-11-16_15215125111115-16.15.41.111-appserver0.log
```

I want Nagios to read it this log file so I can monitor a specific string.

The issue is with **15215125111115** this is the random id that gets generated

Here is my script where the Nagios is checking for the **Logfile** path:

**Veriables:**

```
HOSTNAMEIP=$(/bin/hostname -i)
DATE=$(date +%F)
```

..

> CHECK=$(/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_logfiles/check_logfiles
>   --tag='failorder' --logfile=/test/james-${date +"%F"}_-${HOSTNAMEIP}-appserver0.log
>   ....

I am getting the following output in nagios:

*`could not find logfile /test/James-2018-11-16_-16.15.41.111-appserver0.log`*

**15215125111115** This number is always generated randomly but I don't know how to get nagios to identify it. Is there a way to add a variable for this or something? I tried adding an asterisk "*" but that didn't work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you going to have multiple file that start with "James-2018-11-16" ?

Comment: Correct. a new file with the same name formate gets generated every day.

Comment: Safe to assume you only want to monitor the latest one?

Comment: Could you use some scripting foo to determine the logfile name each day (say using cron) and set it as an ENV variable that this script accesses?  (Doesn't really scale well if there are many of these to monitor)

Answer (score 2):

I would run a separate script, via cron, that identifies the newest log file and makes a symlink to it (named something like "latest.log"). There are several ways you could do this (using `ls -rt | tail` or `find -mtime`, for example).

If the new logfile is created at the same time every day, schedule it to run right after that. If not, have it run every (minute, 5 minutes, whatever), checking for a new log file.

... And then have check_logfiles use that symlink.

Answer (score 0):

there are now predefined macros to be used found in the readme file - check_logfiles directory

```
   $CL_HOSTNAME$ - the hostname without domain.
   $CL_IPADDRESS$ - the IP address of the aforementioned.
   $CL_DATE_YYYY$ - the year (1970...)
   $CL_DATE_MM$ - the month (01..12)
   $CL_DATE_DD$ - the day of month (01..31)
   $CL_DATE_HH$ - the hour (00..23)
   $CL_DATE_MI$ - the minute (00..59)
   $CL_DATE_SS$ - the second (00..59)
   $CL_SERVICEDESC$ - the service description derived from the config file.
   $CL_NSCA_SERVICEDESC$ - dto.
   $CL_NSCA_HOST_ADDRESS$ - the local address 127.0.0.1
   $CL_NSCA_PORT$ - 5667
   $CL_NSCA_TO_SEC$ - 10
   $CL_NSCA_CONFIG_FILE$ - send_nsca.cfg
```